# Google Charts - Not Drawing - JSON Response

Tags: json, charts, google-visualization

I would like to lead with google charts is brand new to me and I could be making a really dumb mistake. I have been working on this all day and no matter what I do, I can't get my google chart to draw using my json data. I think it has something to do with the columns and rows. I've made alot of changes different ways and I've given up at the below information. I'm not getting any errors but my chart isn't loading. I've looked at so many threads and examples now that nothing is making sense. Any help is appreciated!

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <div id="pieDisconnectReasonsChart" style="min-height:271px"></div>
</div>

<script>
       google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDisconnectReasonsChart);

        function drawDisconnectReasonsChart() {

                var jsonData = $.ajax({
                    url: "/Reports/RunDisconnectReasonsReport",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        openDate: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.OpenDate)),
                        closeDate: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CloseDate)),
                    },
                })
                    .done(function (jsonData) {
                        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
                        data.addColumn("string", "SY_OPEN_LBL");
                        data.addColumn("string", "SY_DESCRIPTION");
                        data.addColumn("number", "TOTAL");
                        data.addColumn("number", "PERCTWODEC");
                        data.addColumn("number", "PERC");
                        data.addColumn("number", "ErrMsg");
                Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (row) {
                        data.addRow([
                            row.SY_DESCRIPTION,
                            row.SY_OPEN_LBL,
                            row.TOTAL,
                            row.PERCTWODEC,
                            row.PERC,
                            row.ErrMsg
                    ]);
                });
                var options = {
                    title: 'Disconnect Reasons',
                    titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: 22, bold: true },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom', textStyle: { fontSize: 8 }, alignment: 'center'
                    },
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '98%', height: '80%'
                    }
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieDisconnectReasonsChart'));
                    debugger;
                chart.draw(data, options);
               });
             };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the [data format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#data-format) for a pie chart only allows for two data table columns.
one string and one number.
unless you're providing a custom tooltip, then a third string column is allowed.

---

next, you're manually adding columns and rows to the data table,
so you need to remove the `jsonData` variable from the constructor, here...

from...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);  // <-- remove jsonData
```

to...

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

if you want to create the data table directly from json,
the json must be in a specific format, found here...
[Format of the Constructor's JavaScript Literal data Parameter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam)

with the above method, you would not need to manually add columns and rows,
and the chart would be faster, depending on the amount of data anyway...

---

try removing the extra columns and correcting the constructor,
and it should work, similar to the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDisconnectReasonsChart);

function drawDisconnectReasonsChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn("string", "SY_OPEN_LBL");
  data.addColumn("number", "TOTAL");
  
  data.addRow([
    'CAT A',
    2
  ]);
  data.addRow([
    'CAT B',
    6
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Disconnect Reasons',
    titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: 22, bold: true },
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom', textStyle: { fontSize: 8 }, alignment: 'center'
    },
    chartArea: {
        width: '98%', height: '80%'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieDisconnectReasonsChart'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="pieDisconnectReasonsChart" style="min-height:271px"></div>
```

---

**EDIT**

in the `done` method,
it appears your looping on the keys of your json object.

```
Object.keys(jsonData).forEach(function (row) {
```

instead, loop on the json object itself.

```
jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
```

see following snippet...

```
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDisconnectReasonsChart);

function drawDisconnectReasonsChart() {
  var jsonData = $.ajax({
    url: "/Reports/RunDisconnectReasonsReport",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      openDate: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.OpenDate)),
      closeDate: @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.CloseDate)),
    },
  }).done(function (jsonData) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn("string", "SY_OPEN_LBL");
    data.addColumn("number", "TOTAL");

    jsonData.forEach(function (row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.SY_DESCRIPTION,
        row.TOTAL
      ]);
    });

    var options = {
      title: 'Disconnect Reasons',
      titleTextStyle: { color: 'black', fontSize: 22, bold: true },
      legend: {
        position: 'bottom', textStyle: { fontSize: 8 }, alignment: 'center'
      },
      chartArea: {
        width: '98%', height: '80%'
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('pieDisconnectReasonsChart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
 });
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very similar to an iteration that I had early on but I'm still confused on how to load my json data into the data.addRows??

Comment: I'm sorry to keep bothering you. The reason that I had the object counts in there was because when I use jsonData.forEach I get an error message of "Uncaught TypeError: jsonData.forEach is not a function" that I can't seem to get around.

Comment: will you please share a sample of the json?